# Matching file name pattern in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I've to download a file in an empty directory using robot framework. 
I'm able to download that file.

The downloaded file name pattern would be any of below everytime  :

file_name_1.pdf

file_name_2.pdf

.

.

file_name_NUM.pdf

where NUM is any + integer.

I'm using the Keyword from robot framework OperatingSystem library:

```
                      Wait Until Created
```

But I'm unable to set the file name matching pattern in my code.

Answer (score 1):

OperatingSystem library supports [pattern matching](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Pattern%20matching) for some of the keywords, which applies to `Wait Until Created` keyword. You can do the following to match your pattern:

```
*** Settings *** 

Library    OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases *** 

Test Case 

    Wait Until Created    <path>/file_name_[0-9][0-9].pdf    1 sec
```

The above will match all files with name file_name_<00..99>.pdf